# React context action is called but store doesn't updated (No Redux / React Context / React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am creating an app using react.js - react context(usecontext instead of consumer) and hooks. (No redux/middleware library)

Whenever the component send an action to update the global state, I use 'usecontext' to use the actions and whenever the component needs the data from the global state, I also use 'usecontext' to get the updated state from the global state.

What I am trying to do now is **when the fetching api returns error status, update the error status on global state.**

So on my context file, I export provider and context in the end of the file. The provider has a state and actions are there to update the state.

Following is the Error Context file.
Basically **sendError** action is to update status and message of the error and **clearError** action is for clearing the error status and message.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import errorInitialState from './initialState';

const ErrorContext = createContext();
const { Provider, Consumer: ErrorConsumer } = ErrorContext;

const ErrorProvider = (props) => {
  const [errorState, setErrorState] = useState(errorInitialState);

  const errorActions = {
    sendError: (payload) => {
      setErrorState({
        ...errorState,
        errorStatus: {
          status: payload.status,
          message: payload.message,
        },
      });
    },
    clearError: () => {
      setErrorState({
        ...errorState,
        errorStatus: {
          status: true,
          message: '',
        },
      });
    },
  };

  const value = { errorState, errorActions };
  return (
    <Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </Provider>
  );
};


export {
  ErrorProvider,
  ErrorContext,
};
```

And on my component which want to send an action to update the global state, I use usecontext to use actions. Following is the example of the component.
It's clearing the error **(clearError action)** whenever this component unmounts and this component returns the message of the error from the state if the error status is false.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { ErrorContext } from './context/error';

cosnt Example = () => {
  useEffect(() => () => errorActions.clearError(), []);
  const { errorActions, errorState } = useContext(ErrorContext);

  return (
    {
        !errorState.errorStatus.status
        && <p>{errorState.errorStatus.message}</p>
      }
  );
}
```

The **sendError** action is used from the axios api call, and following is the part of code.

```
        axios
        .put(``, example)
        .then((response) => {
          // handle response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const { response } = error;
          if (response.status === 500) {
            errorActions.sendError({ status: false, message: 'Occured internal server error. Please try again.' });
          }
        });
```

So, what's happening from the UI is that

1. when there's an 500 error
2. error message appears on the Example component
3. when I leave this Example component from the UI (which means, unmounts)
4. clearError action is called
5. but when I come back to Example component on UI, still error message is being displayed.

What I would like to get advise is

- **if this way of using action / state is correct from the component**
- **want to understand why the error message is keep being displayed**